# Why I can't store INET_ATON result to VARBINARY(4)?

Tags: mysql, types, inet-aton

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) says that: Data type VARBINARY(16) is for IPv6 addresses and data type VARBINARY(4) is for IPv4 addresses.

But when I try to store INET_ATON result to VARBINARY(4) column, I get the following error message:

```
Data too long for column varbinary(4)
```

Storing INET_ATON result to VARBINARY(16) is OK!

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the said [`INET_ATON`'s documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton):

> To store values generated by `INET_ATON()`, use an `INT UNSIGNED` column (…)

Comment: It says it in following context: `use an INT UNSIGNED column rather than INT, which is signed`. And MySQL UNSIGNED INT size is exactly 4 bytes (like VARBINARY(4)).

Comment: @NoSkill Is there some problem with doing what it says in the documentation?

Comment: It's a good question though @NoSkill. Did you try casting the result?

Comment: So... Should I EXPLICIT cast result of INET_ATON to VARBINARY(4)?